# How to keep the plugin's cached data when vscode plugin is updated?

Tags: vscode-extensions

I recently developed a vscode plugin, since in the code I would cache some data to local disk, when the plugin was updated, I found that the previously cached data were gone.

After checking, since the data cached by the plugin is stored in the plugin's installation directory, when the plugin is updated, the old plugin will be deleted, so its corresponding data will also be deleted.

Is there any way to realize that the cached data will not be deleted when the plugin is updated?

My current solution, when the vscode plugin is launched, is to find the previous version of the plugin directory by getting the installation directory of the plugin (I've found that when the plugin is updated, the old plugin isn't deleted right away, but rather the next time vscode is launched), and to copy the cached data files from within the previous version of the plugin

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `ExtensionContext.globalStoragePath` variable, and store your cache there. More info here https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_31#_global-storage-path.

Hope this helps